# Can't start bitcoind after wallet encryption (Bitcoin Core)

Tags: bitcoind, encryption

pretty new to the Bitcoin world!

I downloaded Bitcoin Core and got everything up and running.  I then attempted to encrypt my wallet, and after successful encryption can no longer start bitcoind.  When I run bitcoind on the terminal I get the response:

Incorrect or no genesis block found. Wrong datadir for network?

Looked all over but can't find any solutions.  I have a feeling this is a really easy fix but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Is your computer making threats or snide remarks like "All your base are belong to us."